# Apache CustomLog with multiple env

Tags: apache-2.2

In Apache httpd, I want to seperate log file by using SetEnvIf and CustomLog. file1.html access log will be written to file1.log; file2.html access log will be written to file2.log. And finally, all access log are not file1.html and file2.html will be written to default.log

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI file1\.html FILE1
SetEnvIf Request_URI file2\.html FILE2

CustomLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs -l logs/file1.log_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M 1800" common env=FILE1

CustomLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs -l logs/file1.log_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M 1800" common env=FILE2

### Problem here
CustomLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs -l logs/default.log_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M 1800" common env=!FILE1
```

But problem is CustomLog only take 3 args, so I can't set both

```
CustomLog "|/usr/local/apache2/bin/rotatelogs -l logs/default.log_%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M 1800" common env=!FILE1 env=!FILE2
```

With above config, file1.html access log is only in file1.log. But file2.log is in both file: file2.log and default.log

How can I make it?